# how to update user profile image using firebase and Picasso library

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to update the user profile image in the Firebase Realtime Database on my application but I'm unable to get the reference of the current user as I declare it in another activity.

My code and database structure is as follows:

[profile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBgac.png)

as in this current picture and the code, I'm writing manually the id of the child node (gli) because it is the user_name of the current user in the firebase, please help me how can I give it a path through coding.

code:

```
private void profileImage(){

        pImageRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("doctors/doctors_registration/gli/pimage"); 

        pImageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String  imageurl=  String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()) ;
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "link:"+imageurl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(imageurl)
                        .into(profileimg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Please see the screenshot of the database structure and help me how I can get the current user profile image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add inside the onCancelled method:

```
Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
```

Please also note that Picasso is a library that can help you download images and **not** update them in the Realtime Database. If you want to update the image at an existing location, remember that there is no need to read it first. To solve this, please use the following line of code:

```
pImageRef.updateChildren("yourNewUrl");
```

You can also use in this case `addOnCompleteListener()` to see if something goes wrong.

If you however need to update the image right after you read it, then inside the onDataChange() method, use the following line of code:

```
dataSnapshot.getRef().updateChildren("yourNewUrl");
```

Comment: hi Alex but my question is how to get the url of node (gli) ? as it is generated when user signups with it's name. note: here gli is user name that is declared in signup activity and the activity I'm working on is home activity

Comment: What is the value of `imageurl` inside `onDataChange`? Is your `onDataChange` even triggered? Do  you get something printed out in the logcat when using `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`?